# How many simultaneous (concurrent) connections are actually active during a many async request

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

My understanding is the point of `Task` is to abstract out threads, and that a new thread is not guaranteed per `Task`.

I'm debugging in VS2010, and I have something similar to this:

```
var request = WebRequest.Create(URL);

Task.Factory.FromAsync<WebResponse>(
    request.BeginGetResponse, 
    request.EndGetResponse).ContinueWith( 
    t => {  /* ... Stuff to do with response ... */ });
```

If I make `X` calls to this, e.g. start up `X` async web requests, how am I to calculate how many simultaneous (concurrent) connections are actually being made at any given time during execution?  I assume that somehow it is opening only the max it can (in the case `X` is very high), and the other `Tasks` are blocked while waiting?

Any insight into this or how I can check with the debugger to determine how many active (open) connections are existent at a given point in execution would be great.

Basically, I'm wondering if it's handled for me, or if I have to take special consideration so that I do not appear to be attacking a server?

Answer (score 1):

This won't really be specific to `Task`.  The external connection is created as soon as you make your call to `Task.Factory.FromAsync`.  The "task" that the `Task` is performing is simply waiting for the response to get back (not for it to be sent in the first place).  Thus the call to `BeginGetResponse` will fail if your machine is unable to send any more requests, and the response will contain an error message if the server is rejecting your requests due to their belief that you are flooding them.

The only real place that `Task` comes into play here is the amount of time between when the response is actually received by the machine and when your continuation runs.  If you are getting lots of responses, or otherwise have lots of work in the thread pool, it could take some time for it to get to your continuation.

Comment: OK so the server will respond with some `500` or other such error code if it's rejecting my app due to potential flooding.  Though, for the first part I'm unsure how to determine the upper threshold on how many requests my machine is able to send.

Comment: @user17753 Realistically, I doubt you'd ever reach it, and if you did, that method would probably just throw an exception.  If you're actually making that many requests then you're probably doing something wrong...

Comment: It appears to me, that the limit is defaulted to 2 concurrent connections to *same host*.  Apparently, this can be tweaked in the [app.config](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb6y0fyc.aspx)